# Cannot find package "testing/internal/testdeps"

Tags: go

When I try to run `go test` I've got that message:

`package testmain
        imports testing/internal/testdeps: cannot find package "testing/internal/testdeps" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/testing/internal/testdeps (from $GOROOT)
        /Users/myname/go/src/testing/internal/testdeps (from $GOPATH)
FAIL    github.com/dzyanis/olyalya/cmd [setup failed]`

I think it is happened after I've installed a package manager Glide, but I'm not sure. Does anyone know how to fix that?

UPDATE: I've reinstalled Go and everything works well. That's it.

Comment: Where are you running `go test` from? Does it work when you run it with the full package name? Have you inadvertently vendored part of the stdlib?

Comment: @JimB It's inside the folder [dzyanis/olyalya/client](https://github.com/dzyanis/olyalya/tree/master/client) and it's reproduced in both situation `go test` and `go test client_test.go`

Comment: any luck with it? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @OskarSzura unfortunately, I just reinstalled Go and everything works well.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by set:

export $GOROOT=